# How to execute one shell command on completion of other

Tags: linux, shell

I am writing a shell script in which i am generating a csv file and after that attaching and sending this csv file with mutt command in linux .But the problem is that csv file not generated and still the mutt command executes and it says the file not found . So is there any way that i can check that if the command for csv file generation completes then only the mutt command execute.Below are the contents of my script the two statement executed one after other.

```
mysql --user=root --password= erpint -B -e "select * from user_info;" | sed      "s/'/\'/;s/\t/\",\"/g;s/^/\"/;s/$/\"/;s/\n//g" > /home/mayuri/detail.csv
mutt -s "Mutt attach" srini@erpint.com -a /home/mayuri/detail.csv < /home/mayuri/detail.csv
```

Comment: Please share some code - what you're describing is the normal behaviour for a shell script.  (Or did you mean that you want to know when the CSV-generation command fails?  It's not clear from your question.)

Comment: `command_a && command_b`?

Comment: Do you put the csv generating command into the background with `&`? The typical behaviour of a shell script is to execute commands sequentially.

Comment: Follow the link in which file is generated and printed in [shell][1].       [1]: http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/132268-how-create-csv-file-using-shell-script.html

Comment: `mutt ... -a $file < $file` is bizarre.  Why would you attach the file that is being used as the body of the email?

Comment: Even if `mysql` or `sed` fail, that file should be created (it might be 0 bytes, but it should be there).  The only reasons the file wouldn't be there are:  (1) permissions problem (not allowed to create that file), or (2) you have a syntax error causing the shell to exit (such as that unescaped `$` in your double-quoted string).

Answer (score 0):

using bash,

to check if file exist :

```
    #generate you file ....

    if [ ! -f /YourPathToTheFile/yourFile.txt ];
    then
            echo "no file found, exiting and doing nothing";

    fi

    #send your file
```

Answer (score 0):

So, literally, wait for the file to exist:

```
while [ ! -f /home/mayuri/detail.csv ]; do
    sleep 1
done
mutt -s "Mutt attach" srini@erpint.com -a /home/mayuri/detail.csv < /home/mayuri/detail.csv
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use $? which is set to 0 if previous command executed successfully or 1 if it failed:

```
    mysql --user=root --password= erpint -B -e "select * from user_info;" | sed      "s/'/\'/;s/\t/\",\"/g;s/^/\"/;s/$/\"/;s/\n//g" > /home/mayuri/detail.csv
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
      mutt -s "Mutt attach" srini@erpint.com -a /home/mayuri/detail.csv < /home/mayuri/detail.csv
    fi
```